# How Do You Use Remove Handler

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I ma using DevExpress controls (which doesnt matter for this example). I have a lookupEdit control and I never want the EditValue_Changed event to fire. Can I use RemoveHandler to do this? If so can someone give me a code example of doing this? Should I put RemoveHandler in the load event of the user control I am creating? Or does it go in the EditValue_Changed event of the lookupControl?

THIS IS A WINDOWS APP NO POSTBACK....Sorry

Comment: By fire do you mean PostBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RemoveHandler from any event you add to an object within one of your own classes. If the event is defined and being handled within a class you do not have access to, you will not be able to remove its handler events.

It would be instructive to learn where this EditValue_Changed event is firing. If it is firing within your application, then you must have wired it up either in the designer or in the code (which means you should be able to call RemoveHandler without difficulty). If this belongs to a 3rd party library and is auto-configured, you may not have this access.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the control from firing the postback, but you can just not wire up an event handler to a control's event.  You don't need RemoveHandler to do that; just don't attach to the event...  But it seem like the issue is the postback, DevExpress should have a feature in there to fire a client-side event, and keep that all on the client and not have to worry about a server-side postback.

If this doesn't help, could you explain more about the problem?

HTH.

Comment: This is a win app no postback...sorry

Comment: No problem.  What though, is the underlying issue you are having?  Are you just trying to turn off listening for an event, or if there is some bigger problem?  If the former, removehandler should work; otherwise, we need to understand more about the problem to help.

Comment: Just turn off listening for the event. How I do that can you provide me a code snippet. Also do I do it when the whole form is loaded in  the event I wanna turn off.

Comment: See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(VS.80).aspx, you turn it off via whatever form event you want it to happen, so if clicking save button, you put it there and then listening to that event stops.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to subclass the control and override the method(s) that trigger the EditValue_Changed event to fire. If you have access to the source code, find where its being called and if that code can be overridden.